# Send message delivery report

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, messaging

I am able to send and receive messages from my app so far. I have to implement the message delivery report. How do other messaging app ( viber, whatsapp ) send delivery report? Do they use `silent push notification`? Is there any other way to send the delivery report?

Comment: idk how they do it , but if you decide to use silent notification , u can use parse push notification between two user , parse will tell u if the user receive the notification and if he/she open it or not.

Comment: but I assume its easy , you handle on both sides Client and server , If your app got the message its delivered , If he opens the msg Its seen . Its just a flag - It should be fast !  u can use cache so no need to update data base all the time

Comment: but sender has to know that the message was delivered or seen.

Comment: yeah , sender ---> servers ---> receiver // receiver  seen it ---app send to servers that receiver saw it , server send to sender that receiver saw it or the sender side keep checking the flag status .

Comment: oh okey. good suggestion, will work on that.